# Propagating higher-kinded-lifetimes? implementation of `Predicate` not general enough

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a Rust library that lets users define and compose predicates for certain kinds of data. This is all easy when the predicates act on owned data, but it's turning out to be harder when they act on borrowed data. I think it's easier to understand my problem by reading an annotated code example (I'm sorry I couldn't make it shorter, but I think everything in it is required to understand my situation).

```rust
// First, some of the types that I'm interested in writing predicates for. MyValue and
// MyParsedBorrowedValue
struct MyValue {
    a: String
}

struct MyParsedBorrowedValue<'a> {
    _name: &'a str,
    _last_name: &'a str
}

fn parse_value(value: &MyValue) -> MyParsedBorrowedValue<'_> {
    // (imagine some parsing that borrows from MyValue)
    MyParsedBorrowedValue {
        _name: &value.a,
        _last_name: &value.a
    }
}


// Now, imagine I have this trait

trait Predicate<T> {
    fn passes(&self, t: &T) -> bool;
}

// I can write a generic combinator like:

struct Not<T, P: Predicate<T>> {
    p: P,
    _p: std::marker::PhantomData<T>
}

impl<T, P: Predicate<T>> Not<T, P> {
  fn new(p: P) -> Not<T, P> { Not { p, _p: std::marker::PhantomData }}
}

impl<T, P: Predicate<T>> Predicate<T> for Not<T, P> {
    fn passes(&self, t: &T) -> bool {
        !self.p.passes(t)
    }
}

// I can write predicates on MyValue. For example:

struct IsMyValueGood {}

impl Predicate<MyValue> for IsMyValueGood {
    fn passes(&self, _t: &MyValue) -> bool {
        // some processing
        true
    }
}

// I can also write predicates on MyBorrowedParsedValue

struct IsMyParsedBorrowedValueGood {}

impl<'a> Predicate<MyParsedBorrowedValue<'a>> for IsMyParsedBorrowedValueGood {
    fn passes(&self, _t: &MyParsedBorrowedValue<'a>) -> bool {
        // some processing ...
        false
    }
}

// Finally, and this is the most important bit: I want a function that would take a
// Predicate on a "MyParsedBorrowedValue" and transform it into a predicate for a
// MyValue. Something like:

fn map_predicates(p: impl for<'a> Predicate<MyParsedBorrowedValue<'a>>)
    -> impl Predicate<MyValue> {

  // I believe this is a good use of higher-kinded lifetimes, though I'm not very
  // familiar with them.
  struct PredicateMapper<P: for<'a> Predicate<MyParsedBorrowedValue<'a>>> {
      p: P
  }

  impl<P: for<'a> Predicate<MyParsedBorrowedValue<'a>>> Predicate<MyValue> for PredicateMapper<P> {
      fn passes(&self, value: &MyValue) -> bool {
          self.p.passes(&parse_value(value))
      }
  }

  PredicateMapper { p }
}

// This is all good but sadly the following does not compile:

fn compose_predicates() {
    // This compiles:
    let complex_predicate_1 = map_predicates(IsMyParsedBorrowedValueGood{});

    // This doesn't compile!
    // Error: implementation of `Predicate` is not general enough
    let complex_predicate_2 = map_predicates(Not::new(
        IsMyParsedBorrowedValueGood {}
    ));
}
```

Link to compiler explorer https://godbolt.org/z/oonfcMdK3

I understand that the `Not` combinator is not propagating the `for <'a>` outside, which is what `map_predicate` needs to do its job. However, I don't know how I would get `Not` to do that, given that its definition doesn't involve any lifetimes. I guess I could make a custom `NotMyParsedBorrowedValue` that handles the lifetimes in the correct way, but I would prefer having a single `Not` combinator that works for all kinds of predicates. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried adding a type annotation to `map_predicates`? I'm not sure I fully understand the code but I think that it might be important to indicate that the `for<'a> Predicate<MyParsedBorrowedValue<'a>>` in the signature is supposed to be the same as in the body. This might be solved if it receives its own type, restricted by a `where` expression.

Comment: I'm not sure I can do that, given that the lifetime `'a` in for<'a> SOMETYPE<'a>` only applies to the `SOMETYPE` and cannot be accessed from outside of that trait definition. Unless I'm missing what type annotation you suggest adding?

Comment: I have reduced my problem to a simpler version of the code that just uses closure traits and have got a compiler error that looks incorrect (or misleading). I have reported it in https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/92281

Comment: Your code compiles with `RUSTFLAGS="-Zchalk"`. I'd therefore say that you've hit a deficiency in the current trait resolver. I'm not sure if you'll be able to find a workaround...

Comment: Ha! that's interesting. Do you happen to more less know when chalk will be integrated as the official trait resolver? Googling doesn't yield any specific results